# jquery preventDefault not working

Tags: jquery, function

Why is my below preventDefault not working? can't seem to figure it out on this one

```
$(function() {
  $('a.action-link').bind('click', function(e){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#guts').fadeTo(333, 0.2);
      $('ul#slider').fadeOut(333, 'easeOutExpo', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(333, 'easeInExpo');
      });
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: When it isn't working? Can you post a Fiddle sample and explain better what you need?

Comment: The code is syntactically invalid. The browser will not run this code properly since it throws an error...

Comment: Are the `a.action-link` created dynamically? In that case you need to use `.live()` instead of `.bind()`

Comment: @Šime Vidas: +1, did not even think that possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets/parentheses don't match up.  I'm not sure how any of it could work.

```
$(function() {
    $('a.action-link').bind('click', function(e){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#guts').fadeTo(333, 0.2);
            $('ul#slider').fadeOut(333, 'easeOutExpo', function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(333, 'easeInExpo');
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that was only a syntax mistake:

```
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

to

```
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

This works as in the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UnahA/1/